# Implementations in ABCs

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm creating a class hierarchy with a base type that will have 2 (and probably more in the future) subclass implementations.

My first idea is to create an abstract base class (inheriting from `abc.ABC`) with `@abstractmethod`s where necessary (for methods that will be different in my concrete subclasses) but also with common method implementations (for methods used by all concrete subclasses).

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):

    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    def common_method(self):
        """This method is used as-is by all subclasses."""

        return self.var1 + 1

    @abstractmethod
    def specific_method(self):
        """This method needs specific implementations."""
```

Is this good practice (not "best practice"; I'm looking for whether this is an appropriate use of these constructs) for writing a base class? Is using instance methods in my `BaseClass` appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

i would say: yes.

There is a design pattern called *Template Method* which captures what you describe in your question, see https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Base Classes are used to ensure that any derived class provides some specified behavior (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119 -> `rationale`). For example, you want to create custom data manager that must be able to save/load data and must support iteration over elementary pieces of data:

```
import abc


class SavableLoadable(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def save(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def load(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Iteratable(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class MyDataManager(Iteratable, SavableLoadable):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        pass

    def save(self):
        pass

    def load(self):
        pass
```

It is not a class hierarchy. It is a way to define *behaivioral layer* through inheritance. ABCs are very usefull for large-scale projects where different parts are created by different authors and should be able to run together.

So you do not need ABCs to create class hierarchy. ABCs serve another  (although pretty close) purpose.